# segmentation error when using priority queue insert/display functions

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue

I seem to keep get a "Segmentation Error: 11" whenever I run any function(insert and display, unable to tell if delete does it since i can't insert) in the program. I'm not totally sure what it means or where to begin looking to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated on where to begin. I understand that it has something to do with the memory and from what I was able to find it could mean that something is taking up too much memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "priority_queue.h"
//#include <heap.h>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int priority;
    int info;
    struct node* link;
};

class PriorityQueue{
private:
    node* front;
public:
    void Priority_Queue(){
        front = 0;
    }
    void insert(int item, int priority){
        node* temp, *q;
        temp = new node;
        temp->info = item;
        temp->priority = priority;
        if(front == 0 || priority < front->priority){
            temp ->link = front;
            front = temp;
        }
        else{
            q = front;
            while(q->link != 0 && q->link->priority <= priority)
                q = q->link;
            temp->link = q->link;
            q->link = temp;
        }
    }
    void del(){
        node* temp;
        if(front == 0)
            cout << "Underflow" << endl;
        else{
            temp = front;
            cout << "Delete item is: " << temp->info << endl;
            front = front->link;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    void display(){
        node* ptr;
        ptr = front;
        if(front == 0)
            cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
        else{
            cout << "Queue is: " << endl;
            cout << "Priority Item" << endl;
            while(ptr != 0){
                cout << ptr->priority << endl;
                ptr = ptr->link;
            }
        }
    }
};
    int main(){
    int choice, item, priority;
    PriorityQueue pq;
    while(1){
        cout << "1. Insert" << endl;
        cout << "2. Delete" << endl;
        cout << "3. Display" << endl;
        cout << "4. Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter Choice " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
            cout << "Input the item value to be added into the queue" << endl;
            cin >> item;
            cout << "Enter its priority " << endl;
            cin >> priority;
            pq.insert(item, priority);
            break;
            case 2:
            pq.del();
            break;
            case 3:
            pq.display();
            break;
            case 4:
            break;
            default:
            cout << "That is not an option" << endl;
        }
    }
    //while(choice != 4);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're never referencing an uninitialized or invalidated pointer? That's the #1 cause of those crashes. Step through in a debugger just prior to the point of failure to check. Stub in `assert()` if you must.

Comment: It should be `Priority_Queue() { ...}` as a constructor not `void Priority_Queue()` which is a function. You should also get into the habit of declaring your interface in a `.h` or `.hpp` file separate from the implementation in a `.cpp` one.

Comment: Instead of wasting a lot of time coding menus, you should test your `PriorityQueue` class by directly  calling functions to insert and delete.  Once you know the class works correctly, *then* introduce menus.

Comment: Can you write an ordinary, non-priority, FIFO queue?

Comment: @tadman Point completely valid, and I hope the OPs is reading that, but given the OPs code, it should be `PriorityQueue()`,  not `Priority_Queue()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Another good catch. This function isn't called at all, then, which leaves that property uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the class definition. As WhozCraig points out the name of the presumed constructor is wrong, so it never gets called. The corrected code:

```
class PriorityQueue {
private:
    node* front;
public:
    PriorityQueue() : front(nullptr) {
    }
};
```

If you had a look in your debugger you'd probably see that `front` was never properly initialized. In C++ try and use `nullptr` to represent a "null pointer". In C use `NULL`. Using `0` creates a lot of ambiguity even if it "works" for historical reasons.

Comment: @WhozCraig I keep stepping on the same rake!